# How to style using nth-of-type within a ul tag?

Tags: css, css-selectors

How can I use the `nth-of-type` css selector on `<span>` elements that are contained within the `<li>` elements of a `<ul>`?

I would have expected `span:nth-of-type(odd)` and `span:nth-of-type(even)` to work but they did not.

```css
span:nth-of-type(even) {
  background-color: grey;
}
    
span:nth-of-type(odd) {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <span>Test 1</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span> 2 Test</span>
  </li>
</ul>
    
<br>
Should look like this:
<br>
<span>Test 1</span>
<br>
<span> 2 Test</span>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to do it like this:

```
li:nth-of-type(odd) > span {}
li:nth-of-type(even) > span {}
```

The selector `nth-of-type` (and also `first-child`, `last-child` or `nth-child`) refer to their parents. In this case the parent is the `<li>`-tag. So both `<span>`s are *odd elements* as both are the *first-child element*. And both get selected the way you defined the CSS-rule. The CSS-rule here selects their parents as they can be alternating and sets the style for the children accordingly.

Comment: You expanded your answer, mine is a duplicate now so removing it.

Comment: What do you mean by "all selectors are related to their parents"?

Comment: @BoltClock Maybe this was bad wording. What I wanted to say is actually, that `nth-child` or `nth-of-type` mean "*the nth child of a parent*", not the "*nth element within the scope of the body*". That's why the `<span>` is always the "*first child*" within the `<li>`s.

Comment: In that case, you probably meant to refer to those nth selectors, and not just "all selectors".

Comment: @BoltClock That's true, maybe someone could take it too general. I have updated my answer. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1):

The `nth` elements you're looking to count are the `<li>` elements, *not* the `<span>` elements. There's no reason to use `nth-of-type` over `nth-child`, because `<ul>` elements can only contain `<li>` elements as children:

```
li:nth-child(even) > span {
    background-color: gray;
}
li:nth-child(odd) > span {
    background-color: blue;
}
```