# nth-child not working when divs are under other divs

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have a series of divs floated left, then I have div's with different names under these divs that are also floated left. The `nth-child` code will not work on these divs are placed underneath the other floated left divs.  But when they are above them, the nth-child works fine.  I've tried:

`#div:first-child and #div:nth-child(1)`

Again, this only works when the divs are above the other divs, and does not work when the divs are below.

Here are two jfiddles demonstrating when the nth-child works, and also when it doesn't..

What you will see is a series of white divs, and then the two red divs. I'm using the nth-child to give both the two red divs a margin-left of 100px.

When nth-child doesn't work(divs **below** other divs):

http://jsfiddle.net/hsQQn/

When nth-child does work (divs **above** other divs):

http://jsfiddle.net/hsQQn/1/

I would like to get this working so nth-child works when the divs are below the other divs.  At this point I have no idea why it isn't working... any help would truely be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the fiddle that is **not** working the `<div>`s using the `id` are the last two `<div>`s within the container wrapper. So they are neither `first-child` nor `nth-child(2)` of `wrapper`. They are more likely `nth-child(17)` and `nth-child(18)` of their parent wrapper element.

You also have invalid HTML. Every id should be unique. You should use CSS classes instead:

```
div.myclass {}
```

can be used multiple times like this:

```
<div class="myclass"></div>
```

Ids on the other hand:

```
#myid {}
```

can be used one time with this:

```
<div id="myid"></div>
```

Of course you could reference children of the element with the id like this for example:

```
#myid > a {}
```

for this:

```
<div id="myid"><a></a></div>
```

But still there will be only one element that uses the `id` "*myid*".

Comment: Thanks for the answer, you said that the fiddle that is not working doesnt have any element ids with "doublearticlewrapperadmp".. but this is untrue. |doublearticlewrapperadmp" is used in both my html and css.. If it was invalid html.. then neither of the two examples I posted would work because I didn't really change any code from both examples.  All I did was move two html elements up.. and yet the nth-child works in one and it doesnt work in the other.  This is what puzzles me.  I appreciated the answer, but maybe a quick jsfiddle exemplifying your ideology would be helpful.

Comment: Ah sorry, I've updated my answer. Didn't scroll so low. My bad. :) That all the ids work is simply a nice browser behavior. It's still not valid HTML. You can also read this answer from me - it describes basically the same thing: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13034389/1456376

Comment: thanks broham, I didn't realize that the nth-child applies to all the divs in a wrapper.. even when you tell it to be the nth-child of a specific div.. ie. #div:nth-child(2)... weird.. but thanks a lot for opening my eyes up to this

Comment: You're very welcome. Sorry for the confusion in the beginning. As a note: `#div:nth-child(2)` refers to an element with this attribute `id="div"` (could also be an `<a>`-tag. If you want to address all `<div>` elements simply use `div {}`, `div:nth-hcild(2+n) {}` etc.